# How to write a code for user defined list

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, input, procedural-programming

I want to make a 1  dimension list like {x[1],x[2],...}
I want it to be filled by a user, maybe using Input[] function.

Comment: You can get the user to give the entire list in the first Input, and Mathematica will try and figure it out. You could write instructions on the dialog box as to what you are after. Code like `Input[] /. RowBox -> Sequence /. "," -> Sequence[]` would let them just type a comma separated list with no brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be solved. 
Using,

n=Input["Input the dimension of list ", n];
Do[x[i]=Input[x[i]],{i,n}]

Let me know if there is a better way.